# Uploading JPG but not jpg

Tags: php, upload

I have a block of code that uploads an image and creates a thumbnail as long as the extension is lowercase jpg, but it will not upload an image if it is uppercase JPG. When I rename the image, e.g. example.JPG to example.jpg, it will upload. But example.JPG will not upload and I get no error. This does not make any sense to me. Does anyone have an explanation to this? Here is my code:

```
<?php
function createThumbnail($filename) {
  require 'config.php';

  if(preg_match('/[.](jpg)$/', $filename)) {
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename.$path_to_image_directory);
  } else if (preg_match('/[.](gif)$/', $filename)) {
    $im = imagecreatefromgif($path_to_image_directory . $filename);
  } else if (preg_match('/[.](png)$/', $filename)) {
    $im = imagecreatefrompng($path_to_image_directory . $filename);
  }

  $ox = imagesx($im);
  $oy = imagesy($im);

  $nx = $final_width_of_image;
  $ny = $final_height_of_image;

  $nm = imagecreatetruecolor($nx, $ny);

  imagecopyresampled($nm, $im, 0,0,0,0,$nx,$ny,$ox,$oy);

  if(!file_exists($path_to_thumbs_directory)) {
    if(!mkdir($path_to_thumbs_directory)) {
       die("There was a problem. Please try again!");
    } 
  }

  imagejpeg($nm, $path_to_thumbs_directory . $filename);
  $tn = '<img src="' . $path_to_thumbs_directory . $filename . '" alt="image" />';
  $tn .= '<br />Congratulations. Your file has been successfully uploaded, and a      thumbnail has been created.';
  echo $tn;
}
?>
```

The config file:

```
<?php  
$final_width_of_image = 300;
$final_height_of_image = 300;
$path_to_image_directory = '';
$path_to_thumbs_directory = '-tn';
?>
```

Comment: explanation: its your code you have a check for file extension, so that's is why

Comment: on a * NIX system, `.jpg` and `.JPG` are two different animals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this code block you're only allowing lowercase file extensions:

```
if(preg_match('/[.](jpg)$/', $filename)) {
//--lowercase-only--^ 
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename.$path_to_image_directory);
}else if (preg_match('/[.](gif)$/', $filename)) {
    $im = imagecreatefromgif($path_to_image_directory . $filename);
} else if (preg_match('/[.](png)$/', $filename)) {
    $im = imagecreatefrompng($path_to_image_directory . $filename);
}
```

You can fix by placing an [OR condition](http://regexone.com/lesson/conditionals) in the regex:

```
if(preg_match('/[.](jpg|JPG)$/', $filename)) {
// -----uppercase-------^
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename.$path_to_image_directory);
}else if (preg_match('/[.](gif|GIF)$/', $filename)) {
    $im = imagecreatefromgif($path_to_image_directory . $filename);
} else if (preg_match('/[.](png|PNG)$/', $filename)) {
    $im = imagecreatefrompng($path_to_image_directory . $filename);
}
```

Or you can add case insensitivity with the `i` modifier:

```
if(preg_match('/[.](jpg)$/i', $filename)) {
// -------modifier--------^ 
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename.$path_to_image_directory);
}else if (preg_match('/[.](gif)$/i', $filename)) {
    $im = imagecreatefromgif($path_to_image_directory . $filename);
} else if (preg_match('/[.](png)$/i', $filename)) {
    $im = imagecreatefrompng($path_to_image_directory . $filename);
}
```

Comment: **JpG** etc? just make it case insensiteve instead

Comment: sure you where, i believe you :-) its a **/i** at the end by the way :-)

Comment: file extension is never the best idea anyway `mime_content_type` is a better idea

Comment: I totally agree @Dagon, but since the code is already written with regex :) I demonstrated file upload in [my book](http://www.amazon.com/Applied-jQuery-Develop-Jay-Blanchard/dp/0321772563) using `mime_content_type`.

Comment: 1 one star review - dont get to conceited (yet) :-)

Comment: Meh - haters gonna hate. :-)

Answer (score 0):

a better way to do it is to check the file itself rather than the extension, which could always be wrong.

```
    $data = getimagesize($filename);
    switch($data['mime]){
        case('image/png):
            $im = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
            break;
        case('img/jpg'):
        case('image/jpeg'):
        case('image/pjpeg'):
        case('image/x-jps'):
            $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
            break;
        case(self::GIF):
            $im = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
            break;
    }
```